# How to run your own javascript in google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

So there's an online quiz which uses flash, and my friend claims he has a script which pulls the answers from the flash app and displays them. I want to test this out, but I have a question:

How can I add or run this script to chrome so that this happens? In general, how can you run your javascript on a certain site on chrome? This concept interests me, and I didn't know it was possible to force sites to do stuff.

Comment: Try the dev tools https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: There is a plugin for firefox named Greasemonkey, that can run custom Javascript on desired sites, the equivalent for it is Tampermonkey in Chrome but I've not test it yet

Comment: @Serj - accurate info - but this question is tagged with Chrome and not Firefox.

Comment: Make sure that you know what exactly that code does.it's not a good idea to run arbitrary codes on the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open the developers tools by pressing your <kbd>F12</kbd> key or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>. You can also right click on any element in the page and select "inspect element".

Once the developers tools are open, you can navigate to the right most tab called "console". There you can enter arbitrary JavaScript code to be executed on the currently open page.

---

Be careful what you paste into that console though! Someone might give you some malicious code to run. When you open the console while you browse Facebook, they actually display this warning:

[image]

Facebook is just an example. The same warning is applicable for any site.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain, when I paste: <script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";
</script> into the console it says "unexpected token" for the very first "<"

Comment: @user29855 What you quoted is HTML code. You need just the script - which is between the tags.

Comment: @user29855 - and this is why you should never blindly execute code you know nothing about. All you have to do is remove the `<script>` on both sides of the code.

Comment: @Lix I wasn't aware of the dangers of Hello World

Comment: @user29855 - did you know what those `<script>` characters do?

Comment: @Lix I know nothing about programming at all, so no. But I'll take your advice to heart and not execute the script. I'm just messing around with Hello World at this point. By the way, it still doesn't display if I remove the <script>. It now says "TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of nullmessage: "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"stack

Comment: @user29855 That would mean the document contains no element with id `demo`. To do a very simple Hello world, use `console.log()`.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite a broad question. However. there are 3 main answers:

1. For one-time fiddling, you have the power of [Dev Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) at your fingertips. You can run code in the context of the page, examine and debug its own code, make realtime modifications to the DOM etc.
2. To make a script execute every time you load some page, the traditionally used approach is [Userscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey), a notion that came from Firefox. Google Chrome is able (or at least used used to be able) to handle them directly, but now most people use an extension, [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo), that runs userscripts for you.
3. Finally, if you need more powerful tools for interacting with your browser, you have [Chrome Extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/). They are, basically, JavaScript scripts empowered with access to [Chrome APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index). In this context, JS code injected into pages is called [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).